# WPF FlowDocument - Fonts only black and white

Tags: wpf, colors, flowdocument

Our app has a WPF FlowDocumentScrollViewer that shows a flowdocument with text in three font colors: Lavender, #FFFFFFE8, and Orange.  The background of the Viewer is set to transparent, with the window behind it having a Black background.  This works fine for everybody except for one customer.  For him, the Lavender colored text shows up as white, and the text that should be the other two colors shows up as black.  Black text is hard to read against a black background.

I imagine there is some windows setting that is causing the font colors to be displayed in black and white on his computer.  Can anyone please point me to the correct setting?  And is there anyway to override this behavior in the xaml or code behind?

Comment: This user could be in High-Contrast mode.

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried the High-Contrast themes under XP and it didn't cause the problem.  The screen shot the customer sent me doesn't look like High-Contrast either.